# Visual Studio project cannot resolve symbols of other projects added as externals

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have created a c# project. In the same solution I have added as externals 3 more projects (.csproj) but it fails when I try to load assemblies from the externals. On resharper I get "Cannot resolve symbol". In addition the main project and the three externals have the same Target Framework (4.5.2). I am using visual studio 2015. Any cases or mismatches on this problem?

Comment: I bet, this is because VS cannot resolve symbol:\ Now try find which one.

Comment: It may be in config files or somewhere else?

Comment: You mean you have three project references? I assume you're not able to compile your project?

Comment: I have added a folder named Externals on the solution and added 3 existing projects inside it. But I cannot use namespaces from them on my main project.

Comment: so, you not added them as references?

Comment: @vasily.sib ,  yes I have not added them as references. You think that if I load their dlls it may work?

Comment: Sure, if you add them as a references to your project - they will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the other projects to your solution by selecting your solution in the Solution Explorer, then display the context menu and select the menu "Add" and then "Existing project".  Do this for all three projects.
This is also explained on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460187.aspx

Then add these projects as project references to your main project. You can do this by selecting your main project in the Solution Explorer, display the context menu and select the "Reference" menu item. A detailled explanation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx

Visual Studio should now be able to resolve the symbols.